# Two rows in owl carousel 2

Tags: carousel, rows, owl-carousel-2

is it possible to do such a carousel as in the diagram below? I tried to use OWL Carousel 2 but I can not deal with 2 rows for desktop.

[image: rows in carousel]

Thanks in advance for the hints.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? If yes can you please share me how achieved it?